# How to avoid creating lots of methods, while using principle of least knowledge?

Tags: design-patterns

I am trying to design an interface using 'Facade pattern'. However as pointed out here:

http://www.scribd.com/doc/6599003/7/Principle-of-Least-Knowledge-PLK

this is forcing me to create lots of accessor methods in the class. According to the above link, as a variation of PLK, we can return interface reference as opposed to reference to a concrete object.

My question is how does this solve the problem? once we return an interface reference, we need to instantiate with the appropriate class anyway. Ultimately we will end up calling a method from the that object right?

Comment: If you are using a Facade pattern, then the object is to simplify use of the wrapped object. The Facade itself may be quite complex. Not a lot of point in having a facade if you expose the wrapped object or one of its interfaces directly.

Answer (score 0):

Saying that you are *designing an interface using a certain pattern* sounds like you’re using the pattern without knowing why. Is there a design problem you are trying to solve? If yes, it should be clear if returning an interface solves the problem or not.

As the name implies, the Facade Pattern is used to hide something you don’t want your callers to see. A good reason to hide something is complexity – if you have some complex code, you can hide the complexity behind a facade that will offer the caller a simplified interface. This is nice, because the coupling between the caller and the called code is loose: if the implementation details change, you can hide the changes behind the facade and the caller doesn’t have to care.

One of the ways to hide something is to hide the precise type. Let’s say you have a class `Foo` that implements `Bar` and `Baz`, and a caller that just needs to use methods declared in `Baz`. Then one way to hide the complexity is to return just the interface: “something that implements `Baz`”. Then the caller doesn’t have to care about `Foo` or `Bar`, and even better, the caller can’t use `Foo` or `Bar` *at all*. You are free to change `Foo` and `Bar` as you wish, which is a good thing.